# I'm using openoffice to create sql and the dates are turning into numbers in the calculations

Tags: sql, date, openoffice.org

This is my calculation

```
="insert into tableName values('" & A1 &",'" & B1 & "','"& C1 &"','" & D1 & "','" & E1 & "','" & F1 & "','" & G1 & "');"
```

and the data in the cells

```
01/05/13   1   2   3   4   5   6
```

But when the calculations completes the string is

```
insert into tableName '41279', '1', '2', '3', '4', '5' ,'6'
```

if I add an `'` to the end of the date so it's `01/05/13'` then it keeps the date correctly

Comment: ... what's your question again?

Comment: the date from cell A1(01/05/13) is turning into the number 41279 when its put into the calculation. I don't want that crazy number i want the date so I can put it in to the database

Comment: Its not a crazy number. Its the number of days since 1/1/1900

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[TEXT](http://wiki.openoffice.org/wiki/Documentation/How_Tos/Calc%3a_TEXT_function) function is your answer. Use "dd/mm/yy" (or "mm/dd/yy" if you are in US) as a format

Answer (score 0):

OpenOffice doesn't like to concatenate dates with strings.  Try something like below:

```
="insert into tableName values('" & TEXT(A1; "dd/mm/yyyy") & ",'" & B1 & "','"& C1 &"','" & D1 & "','" & E1 & "','" & F1 & "','" & G1 & "');"
```

You could also use the Concatenate function:

```
=CONCATENATE("INSERT INTO TableName VALUES ('"; TEXT(A1; "dd/mm/yyyy"); "')")
```